# Select multiple rows containing values from one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Actually my question is almost the same with [MySQL: Select multiple rows containing values from one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818004/mysql-select-multiple-rows-containing-values-from-one-column), I want to find the car_id of the cars that have MAKE='FORD' AND COLOR='SILVER', so in this case here it will returns car_id 1 and 2.

PS: There could be multiple criteria at once, like I can search by MAKE + CARLINE + COLOR, MAKE + CARLINE, and etc.

```
table_cars

+----+--------+----------+-----------+
| id | car_id | name     | value     |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1      | MAKE     | FORD      |
| 2  | 1      | CARLINE  | FIESTA    |
| 3  | 1      | COLOR    | SILVER    |
| 4  | 1      | TOPSPEED | 210KM/H   |
| 5  | 2      | MAKE     | FORD      |
| 6  | 2      | CARLINE  | FOCUS     |
| 7  | 2      | COLOR    | SILVER    |
| 8  | 2      | TOPSPEED | 200KM/H   |
| 9  | 3      | MAKE     | HOLDEN    |
| 10 | 3      | CARLINE  | ASTRA     |
| 11 | 3      | COLOR    | WHITE     |
| 12 | 3      | TOPSPEED | 212KM/H   |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select multiple rows containing values from one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818004/mysql-select-multiple-rows-containing-values-from-one-column)

Comment: Is there anything different between your question and the one you linked and I marked as duplicate?

Comment: This is a bad database model, because it doesn't model a car. A car has attributed like brand, color, speed, etc. Your table just has some "things" of a name and a value. Why do you call your table table_cars at all? Call it table_something and your car_id something_id and you can use it for your DVD collection and your laundry, too.

Comment: @jpw that question on wants to return 1 row, but I want to return more that one row

Comment: @ThorstenKettner this is just an example copied from the question I refereed to, my actual database is just like you said, it will contains multiple types of data in it.

Comment: @Ping The answer in that question would have worked for you too... see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1df75/4 for an example.

Comment: @jpw Yes I knew that, but I might select more than 2 criteria, like if I need to select the rows based on 5 criteria, I will need to join 5 tables already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select car_id
from your_table
group by car_id
having sum(name = 'MAKE' and value = 'FORD') > 0
and sum(name = 'COLOR' and value = 'SILVER') > 0
```

Comment: The strings should be upper case.

Comment: Only if a case-sensitive collation is used.

Comment: Ah, okay, something special in MySQL. I didn't know that.

Comment: No, that is the case for all DB engines.

Answer (score 0):

Try with self join as below:

```
SELECT distinct car_id
FROM mytable mt1 INNER JOIN mytable mt2
ON   mt1.car_id = mt2.car_id
WHERE mt1.name = 'MAKE'
AND   mt1.value = 'FORD'
AND   mt2.name = 'COLOR'
AND   mt2.value = 'SILVER'
```